# Remove duplicate lines from file that are in a different order

Tags: text-processing, awk, text, uniq

My file is like this:

```
alice, bob
bob, cat
cat, dennis
cat, bob
dennis, alice
```

I want to remove lines where same words have been repeated in reverse order. In this example, `bob, cat` and `cat, bob` are repeated, so cat bob should be removed and my output should be

```
alice, bob
bob, cat
cat, dennis
dennis, alice
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Any restrictions regarding the other lines? I.e. can the fields be resorted and the lines be resorted, too?

Comment: no such restrictions. sorting can be done any number of times..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hash that is keyed on the sorted elements:

```
$ perl -lne 'print unless $h{join ",", sort split /, /, $_}++' file
alice, bob
bob, cat
cat, dennis
dennis, alice
```

---

For exactly 2 fields, something like this might sufficce

```
$ awk -F', ' '!seen[$2 FS $1]; {seen[$0]++}' file
alice, bob
bob, cat
cat, dennis
dennis, alice
```

Comment: idk what the perl script does but that awk script will use a lot more memory than necessary, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533876/133219 for the idiomatic awk approach.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic awk answer:

```
$ awk -F', ' '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
alice, bob
bob, cat
cat, dennis
dennis, alice
```

The general approach for any number of fields is to sort them and use the sorted list as the index to seen[].

Comment: Can you please explain how logic?

Comment: @DeathMetal It creates a common index out of each pair of key fields by putting them in greatest-first order so `A B` and `B A` both become the index `B A`. Then it just tests to see if the given index has been seen before - first time either `A B` or `B A` is encountered in the input `seen["B A"]++` is `0`, 2nd time it's 1, and so on. The `!` at the front ensures that the default action of printing the current input line only occurs when `seen["B A"]++` is zero, i.e. the first time its seen in the input.

Answer (score -1):

This sorts every line by its fields, then the file and pick unique lines only

```
while read line
  do
    echo $line |
    tr ' ,' '\n' |
    sort |
    tr '\n' ','
done < 1 |
sed -e 's/^,//' -e 's/,$//' -e 's/,,/\n/g' |
sort -u
```

Comment: It will also strip some white space, interpret escape sequences, do globbing, word splitting and file name generation, be extremely slow and rely on sed being able to operate on a non-POSIX-compliant input stream. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for a description of some of the issues.